# Oracle Apex 20.2 Interactive grid - setting value of radio group with javascript

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-20.2

I have a interactive grid with a radio group column. In apex 20.2 this type of column shows the chosen value, and only when you click on the cell do the radio buttons show.

I have some javascript logic that sets the value of this cell:

var grid = apex.region('ig_my_region').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews','grid');

var model = grid.model;

record = model.getRecord (l_id); //id is determined earlier in the script

model.setValue(record,'AVAILABLE', l_check); //l_check is a variable (Y/N).

Now this does set the value of the cell, but the value does not show on the grid until the cell is clicked.

[image: image.png]

when clicked we see it is set to Yes

[image: image.png]

and when you leave the cell

[image: image.png]

What needs to be done for the value to be shown right away? This issue is only with the radio group column. I am setting other columns in this fashion and the values are shown.

Edit: the grid is put into edit mode on page load.

Comment: Did you tried refreshing your item (radio button) after setting value via JavaScript ?

Comment: It is not a item that is being set. It is a column in a interactive grid.

Comment: Ahh okay. Not entirely sure for resolution. You mentioned it is working for other types. If possible change radio group to select list with Yes and No option?

Comment: No, it is not a possibility, otherwise this question would not be here. The client wants this column to be a radio group. Another issue is the fact that they (oracle) decided to display radio groups in this way...